# How to get password from database using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, devise, password-recovery

**I'm using rails 3.2.1 + devise 2.0.4**

**My problem is that in my website only :** Admin will create new users no direct registration for users. Now when Admin create new_user confirmation mail will be send to the user email id. The content of the mail is

```
user_name 
user_password
```

But the password come in encrypted format.

How I'll get password in readable form.

Answer (score 0):

Devise does hashing, so you're not going to get the password from the database - period. You should have the password when you create the user, so why are you trying to fetch it from the database anyway?

Also, sending passwords in cleartext emails? Ugh.